# Replace a part of a varchar2 column in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, replace, oracle-sqldeveloper, varchar2

I've a **varchar2** column in a table which contains a few entries like the following
*TEMPORARY-2 TIME ECS BOUND -04-Insuficient Balance*
I want to update these entries and make it *TEMPORARY-2 X*. What's the way out?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you can either use character functions such as `substr()`,
`replace()`

or a regular expression function - `regexp_replace()` for instance.

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 'TEMPORARY-2 TIME ECS BOUND -04-Insuficient Balance'
  3      from dual
  4  )
  5  select concat(substr( col, 1, 11), ' X')             as res_1
  6       , regexp_replace(col, '^(\w+-\d+)(.*)', '\1 X') as res_2
  7  from t1
  8  ;
```

Result:

```
RES_1         RES_2
------------- -------------
TEMPORARY-2 X TEMPORARY-2 X
```

So your `update` statement may look like this:

```
update your_table t
   set t.col_name = regexp_replace(col_name, '^(\w+-\d+)(.*)', '\1 X')
 -- where clause if needed.
```